# How to easily track how long my laptop battery actually lasted?

Tags: windows-7, hibernate, battery-life

I have a new laptop battery, and I want to find out how long it actually did last before my PC went to hibernation mode (due to low battery) without me being present.

I tried two stopwatches, but they simply seems to save some start date and so the time the laptop was off will be included in the time after the next resume.

Any simple ideas?

Comment: Google "battery monitor windows" and see if there's one that logs to a file at regular intervals.

Comment: What's your operating system? Did you check the event log?

Comment: @and31415 My OS is Win 7. I didn't check the event log. When I looked into that topic some time ago, I think I read, that it is disabled by default and I discarded that path because it looked to be complicated. Although now I cannot reproduce what can be complicated concerning some logging.

Comment: @Lester When the system is hibernated, the event logger service (and everything else) is stopped; after resuming, the event logger service will be started again. Once you know when the last event was logged right before hibernating and the time you left your laptop, you can do some math to get a rough estimate.

Comment: @and31415 Sounds sensible. Can you tell me where to look exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Using the Event Viewer

> Event Viewer is a tool that displays detailed information about significant events (for example, programs that don't start as expected or updates that are downloaded automatically) on your computer. Event Viewer can be helpful when troubleshooting problems and errors with Windows and other programs. For more information about Event Viewer, see [What information appears in event logs (Event Viewer)?](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/what-information-appears-in-event-logs-event-viewer)
>
> <sub>Source: [Open Event Viewer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/open-event-viewer#1TC=windows-7)</sub>

When the system is hibernated, the event logger service (and everything else) is stopped; after resuming, the event logger service will be started again. Once you know when the last event was logged right before hibernating and the time you left your laptop, you can do some math to get a rough estimate.

1. Log on with an administrator account.
2. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type or paste `eventvwr.msc` in the text box, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. Expand the **Windows Logs** category, and click the **System** item.
4. Click **Filter Current Log** either from the **Actions** band or the **Action** menu.
5. Choose **Custom range** from the **Logged** drop-down list.
6. Specify the earliest date and time from which you want logged events. If you're unsure about the right time, pick some value enough in the past.
7. Select **Power-Troubleshooter** from the **Event sources** list.
8. Type `1` in the event ID text box, then click **OK**.
9. Make sure the filtered event list is sorted by date in descending order (latest event first). Event ID `1` is triggered every time the system awakes from either sleep or hibernation; latest event available should match the date and time when you manually resumed the system.
10. Open the **Filter Current Log** dialog again.
11. Choose **Custom range** again from the list. Leave the **From** values as is, and change the **To** date/time values in order to match those of the awake event you filtered earlier, plus one minute.
12. Add **Kernel-Power** to the **Event sources** list.
13. Type `1,42` in the event ID text box, then click **OK**.
14. Find the event ID `42` which happened right before the last awake event. That should coincide, more or less, with the date and time when Windows entered the hibernation mode.

**Note** The steps above were tested with Windows 7, and should apply just as well to Windows Vista and Windows 8.x.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a program such as [Battery Eater](http://batteryeater.com/news.html), which seems to be what you were looking for. Here is an example of what it looks like:

[image]

In the set of instructions below, I assumed you wanted to test your laptop battery while it was idling, and not under load. Setting Battery Eater up is extremely simple, here is what you need to do:

1. Download and run the program
2. Click `Options` and make sure `Benchmark mode` is set to `Idle`
3. Plug your laptop into a power source, and make sure `Begin Testing when disconnecting AC` is checked
4. Disconnect your laptop from the power source, and the test will begin

If you wanted to test the battery while the laptop was under load, just ignore step three in the instructions above.

To have a look at the results (after the laptop has died), just re-open Battery Eater after you turn your laptop back on. You will now be able to see a graph of your battery's discharge rate, and also the time it took to deplete.

For a more in-depth review and tutorial on Battery Eater, have a look at the one MakeUseOf did [HERE](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/benchmark-laptops-battery-life-battery-eater/).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Seems indeed like what I am looking for. I will give it a try! :)

Comment: is this a freeware?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the following VBS script, which logs charging and discharging time to a text log file:
https://gist.github.com/knee-cola/49a7cedf3675da485e76d6e1e5e838c6

It uses windows instrumentation to get the current charging state.

You will need to manually setup Windows Task Scheduler to run the script, but it's not too complicated ... instructions can be found at the given link.